# EXCEL - Match values from one sheet to another and then paste results

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make the most user-friendly excel spreadsheet I can. This spreadsheet takes a name that the user puts in for a client, sometimes a first name and sometimes first and last. I have another sheet with the full list of clients, first and last names.

What I need to do is look at the user input, match that name to the client list sheet, and then paste that into the original sheet.

Example:

USER SHEET

```
       A           
1    Jane
2    Helen Smith
3    John
```

CLIENT LIST SHEET

```
       A         B
1   Johnson     Jane
2    Smith      Helen
3    Brown      John
```

I need the User Sheet to look like

```
       A                 B
1    Jane           Johnson, Jane
2    Helen Smith    Smith, Helen
3    John           Brown, John
```

I know this might be a complicated formula, I've tried to write a whole bunch of different ones but none of them are really doing what I need them to.

Most of the problem is that I need other people I work with, who don't know how to use excel and sometimes aren't able to write the full names, to be able to use this spreadsheet once I have a generic formula in there, and all that would need to be changed is the Client List sheet.

Hopefully I provided enough detail in here. Thanks for any help you give me in advance, super appreciate it. If I find a solve I'll post it.

Comment: This should be super simple with the `Match` and/or `Index` functions. Why don't you show us what you've tried so far, and explain what is not working about it?  On the other hand, doing a first name match is only as reliable as you can ensure there are no clients with the same first name. If you have two clients Jane Johnson and Jane Stevenson, no formula will ever be able to correctly determine which "Jane" you meant in column A of User Sheet.

Comment: *sometimes a first name and sometimes first and last.* <-- This is a bad idea. You should normalize and enforce the expected inputs.

Comment: *people I work with... sometimes aren't able to write the full names* <-- Serious question: Why not? Do you work with kindergartners?

Comment: @DavidZemens We try to enforce, but the intake load is heavy so even though they usually write full names, sometimes they don't and it's difficult for me to edit each individually so I would rather not.

Comment: sure, sh|t happens when you use a spreadsheet for data collection :) I get that. But the biggest issue is the limitation imposed by string matching: If you only have a part of a name (first name, part of a first name, etc.) then you have to assume that the Lookup list (Client Sheet) **doesn't** contain any possible duplicates. Otherwise, it is impossible to guarantee accurate results, because a function (whether done via worksheet or complicated UDF with VBA) simply cannot ascertain from the string "Jane" whether it is "Jane Johnson" or "Jane Smith" or "Jane Somethingelse".

Comment: IOW, anyone here can easily write a solution that will work for these three cases in your example, but which are all but guaranteed to fail if the client list contains duplicate first name keys.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. In your Client sheet, in the third column build a formula that combines first & last name, like:

```
=B1&" "&C1
```

Then select the range of names (columns A:C) and Insert Table (without headers). You can enter the header labels later:

[image]

From the Formulas Ribbon, open the Name Manager. Define a new name called "ClientNames" and have it refer to the fullname column (modify the Refers To formula based on your table's name & column header name):

[image]

Then, on your User Sheet, select column A, and from Data ribbon Data Validation. Allow "List" and set the "Source" formula to `=ClientNames`.

[image]

Finally, instruct your users to choose a client name from the validation list. This will prevent them from making bad inputs and also enforce a standard against the "Users" worksheet.

[image]

If you still need the formatted LastName,FirstName in column B, then do a formula:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))&", "&LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This formula might be looking too complex but it is simple,

use this in column B of your user sheet and drag across the rows.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),Sheet2!B:B,0),1)&", "&INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),Sheet2!B:B,0),2),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),Sheet2!A:A,0),1)&", "&INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),Sheet2!A:A,0),2),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!B:B,0),1)&", "&INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!B:B,0),2),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0),1)&", "&INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0),2),""))))`

This formula is for `A1`, you can modify it if you want to start from searching `A2`. Let me know if you need help. This might look big but its very useful for dragging across ranges.